# Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder not found

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to configure the Google Ad-words API but when I execute my code, the following error appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder' not found in
>   /var/www/html/contabilidade/post-manager/wp-content/themes/monitor/functions/backend/access.php
>   on line 368 ( ! ) Error: Class
>   'Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder' not found in
>   /var/www/html/contabilidade/post-manager/wp-content/themes/monitor/functions/backend/access.php
>   on line 368

This is my code to get values:

```
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201708\cm\CampaignService;
    use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

    class GetCampaignsWithAwql {

    const PAGE_LIMIT = 500;

    public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
        AdWordsSession $session) {
      $campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class);

      // Create AWQL query.
      $query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Status ORDER BY Name';

      // Create paging controls.
      $totalNumEntries = 0;
      $offset = 0;
      do {
        $pageQuery = sprintf('%s LIMIT %d,%d', $query, $offset, self::PAGE_LIMIT);
        // Make the query request.
        $page = $campaignService->query($pageQuery);

        // Display results from the query.
        if ($page->getEntries() !== null) {
          $totalNumEntries = $page->getTotalNumEntries();
          foreach ($page->getEntries() as $campaign) {
            printf(
                "Campaign with ID %d and name '%s' was found.\n",
                $campaign->getId(),
                $campaign->getName()
            );
          }
        }

        // Advance the paging offset.
        $offset += self::PAGE_LIMIT;
      } while ($offset < $totalNumEntries);

      printf("Number of results found: %d\n", $totalNumEntries);
    }

    public static function main() {
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';
    // OAuth2TokenBuilder
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile($KEY_FILE_LOCATION)
        ->build();

    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the OAuth2
    // credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();
    self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session);

  }
```

I used an example from Google and still get the same error, I can't resolve that error.
Any suggestion, links? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using composer at the beginning or bringing in any sort of autoloader?

Comment: I'm using from the other app. @castis